# How can I install a curtain rod on a drywall?

Tags: drywall, curtain-rail

Originally I though this would be an easy process, however where I used to live all the houses are pure concrete, therefore something like this used to be relatively simple. My question is how can I attach a rod to a drywall?. I realize this questions might sound really ignorant, but please bear with me, I've never done anything with a drywall, I am currently living in the U.S., and my house like pretty much every other house here has drywalls.

It seems to me that if I just do it in the Drywall it will surely fall down, as it is not strong enough, my intuition tells me that behind the drywall there has to be some wood frame where presumably people attach the rods?. I do not have blue prints for my house, what would be a good way to know where I should install this rod?.

As a note the previous owner had curtain rods installed, but he removed them. So it is clear to me that this is possible, I just have no idea how.

This is a 2000 house that I just bought if that is relevant. Wood frame, brick veneer on the outside and drywall on the inside.

Any help, or perhaps good tutorials on how to do this, or what I need to buy would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is this question a repeat? Another post has the same question and is tagged "drywall", though it doesn't often refer to drywall: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8868/how-do-i-hang-curtain-rods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically most wood framed houses will have wood framing running from floor to ceiling on either side of the window.  If you mount an inch and half away from the edge of the window opening you will most likely hit wood.

But the best way is to head to the store and buy a stud finder.  It's a small hand held device that will find the wood/metal framing under the drywall.  It's a handy item to keep around the house when ever you need to hang something that needs more support.

Comment: +1 for the stud finder, was hoping something like this would exist!

Comment: just read the instructions that comes with it, with a little playing around it will be pretty easy to find things behind the wall.  Don't buy the absolute cheapest, but the step up from the cheapest is fine for the average home owner.  Any hardware store will have them.

Answer (score 1):

Use drywall anchors which come in [many shapes and sizes](https://www.google.com/search?q=drywall%20anchor&client=firefox-a&hs=PHO&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=uB7tU86YBYGZyASjwYHQCQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1048&bih=722&dpr=1.09). Select the one suitable for the load being applied.

For heavier loads, such as bookshelves, use a [stud finder](https://www.google.com/search?q=drywall%20anchor&client=firefox-a&hs=PHO&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=uB7tU86YBYGZyASjwYHQCQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1048&bih=722&dpr=1.09#channel=sb&q=studfinder&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbm=isch) and attach the shelves through the drywall to the wood stud.

Comment: Drywall anchors are great for hanging photos and other decorations, they are not recommended for curtains. Especially if you have children or cats.

Comment: Much as 2 phase electrical service is suitable for many use cases - despite some needing three phase, hollow wall anchors come in many sizes. Some suitable for loads imposed by many window treatments in normal circumstances. If children are climbing the curtains, the priority solution is not stronger anchors.

Comment: The most you can support with a drywall anchor is 50 pounds.  But this is 50 pounds sheer, which means downward force flush with the dry wall.  Curtain rods support there weight 3-5 inches from the wall causing a lot of leverage against the drywall anchors.  Sheers or thin curtains might not weight much, but if you go with nice ones you can be looking at 30 pounds of fabric.  Plus the abuse they get from opening and closing, those drywall anchors will not hold for very long.  And you do have to take the kid/cat factor in as @Tester101 says.  If only takes a second for a kid to climb.

Comment: @diceless There are drywall anchors that will fasten ADA grab bars and more conventionally styled anchors rated for several hundred pounds. See: http://www.wingits.com//pdfs/71183455WINGITS_Fasteners.pdf In the US, the big box home improvement stores often carry similar or identical products in stock.

Comment: @benrudgers The size and strength of the anchor is not the weak point in the system, the drywall is. Drywall (gypsum board) is a finishing material, not a structural one. It's nothing more than plaster between two sheets of paper.

Comment: @tester101 Gypsum board is frequently used as a structural component particularly as a shear diaphragm, both internally and as sheathing. The relevant aspect being that in these applications the fasteners transfer load to the *structural frame*. Like all materials, gypsum board has its limitations and capabilities and as is typical in construction there are standards to which it is manufactured and certifications such as UL. Rules of thumb are useful but of necessity lack insight.

Comment: @benrudgers Here is a real work test of dry wall anchors.  http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/reviews/4224987.  Note the line, "When they did fail at 63 pounds, the fasteners took massive chunks of drywall with them"